# How to fill ListBox with data entries programatically in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, linq, ria

Trying to fill the listbox programatically I have written the following code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            TestDBContext context = new TestDBContext();
            context.Load(context.GetTaskQuery());

        var taskList = GetTasks();
        foreach (var t in taskList)
        {
            ListBoxTaskItems.Items.Add(t);

        }
    }

    private List<TaskItem> GetTasks()
    {
        var tasks = from t in context.Tasks
                    select new TaskItem(t);
        return tasks.ToList();
    }
```

The problem is that the code above alway returns an empty ListBox. Does anyone know how to modify the existing code or another way to programatically fill the listbox with the data entries?

**Edit #1:** While debugging I've noticed that GetTasks() method is executed before context.GetTaskQuery() and I gues this is the reason for an empty ListBox. Nevertheless I don't know how to fix the code in order to populate the ListBox.

Thank you!

Comment: One thing I had to do when adding Grids as content was to set the row height (via the RowDefinition) even though my inner content, such as Rectangles, had that specified. So it might be that the content is getting added but just isn't being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody posted another solution, then for whatever reason deleted it, but that might work better. I just tried it in some code I'm working on and found it was faster:

```
Binding bind = new Binding();

bind.Source = GetTasks();

ListBoxTaskItems.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, bind);
```

(Substitute this for the foreach statement).

Answer (score 0):

I'd try it like this inside your foreach statement:

```
ListBoxItem listBoxItem = new ListBoxItem();

listBoxItem.Content = t;

ListBoxTaskItems.Items.Add(listBoxItem);
```

I do something similar and it works when adding Grids to a ListBox, so as long as a TaskItem is something acceptable as Content that should do it.